# Why vertical scroll bar appearing when height is 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have a web page index2.html whose height is 100%. It has 3 `div`: 1st one's height is 20%, 2nd one's height is 70% and 3rd one's height is 10%.

This is its whole HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

#div_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#div_middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#div_footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div_header">
</div>
<div id="div_middle">
</div>
<div id="div_footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I display the web page on a browser (IE 11 and Chrome), a vertical scroll bar is showing up. I dont understand why there is a vertical scroll bar when the height of page is 100% set and the sum of height of 3 div (20% + 70% + 10%) is also 100%. Why this is happening? How can I fix this issue?

```css
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

#div_header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 20%;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}

#div_middle {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70%;
 border: 1px solid red;
}

#div_footer {
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_header">
</div>
<div id="div_middle">
</div>
<div id="div_footer">
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/srhcan/wgshmd7s/)

Comment: have you tried overflow-y:hidden?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For two reasons

1. The body has a default margin that you'd need to eliminate with `body {margin:0}`
2. The the other issue is that your borders factor into the size of your elements and increase the height. You can fix this by adding `div {box-sizing:border-box}`

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wgshmd7s/1/)**

Comment: `div {box-sizing:border-box;}` did not work in IE 11. It worked in Chrome.

Comment: @srh - Works fine in IE11 as my fiddle shows. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: It is not in my case. My IE is Version 11.0.9600.18314. This web page is in a web application running on Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem in your example was the body margin (default in most browsers) and the borders which made the divs width 100% + 2 pixels (border on left and right) and the height was affected the same way.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#div_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: blue;
}

#div_middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  background-color: red;
}

#div_footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_header">
</div>
<div id="div_middle">
</div>
<div id="div_footer">
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

And yes you could also set `box-sizing:border-box;` in your css to fit the borders in the 100% div. This along with setting `margin: 0;` to your `<body>` element would be the correct way to go in fixing your issue.

You can also read about box-sizing [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div_header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#div_middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#div_footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_header">
</div>
<div id="div_middle">
</div>
<div id="div_footer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

```
* {
     overflow: hidden;
  }
```

This worked.

Comment: I think it's not a solution to hide the problem....

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the scroll bar is because you are not accounting for the box model.  The percentages do not account for margin, or borders.  So by adding a 1 px border and not removing the margins, the percentages will make the boxes slightly taller the the view screen.

Try this.

```html
*{
 margin: 0;
 
}
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}

#div_header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
 background-color: #23408;
}

#div_middle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
 background-color: #444;
}

#div_footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
 background-color: #123854;
}
```